# How to add value to decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal, addition

I have some list of gps coordinates of latitude and longitude. How can I add random int value at the end of the float variable of latitude. I have tried this...

```
float log = 77.567635f;
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.Next(1, 20);
```

Let suppose value of r is 12, I would like to add to log '77.567635' + r.

My expecting result will be '77.567647'

Comment: Does this question really have any connection to coordinates or is it just "How to add a value at a specific post-point?"?

Comment: divide `r` by `1000000f` before you add it to `log`?

Comment: You can parse your float to string, get the whole value after the `.` and parse it to an int, do the operations you want and then you do the opposite way.

Comment: @HansPassant any variable will be accepted to accomplish this scenario. Do you have any code solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is specify the precision of the floating point number first. If for example the precision is 0.000001 (like in your example) you can multiply the randomly generated number with this precision and add it to your coordinate.

```cs
float log = 77.567635f;
Random rand = new Random();
float r = rand.Next(1, 20) * 0.000001f;
log = log+r;
```

Comment: `float` does not have enough precision, you'll need to recommend `double`.

Comment: @wserr thanks for your solution i got my expecting result `rand.Next(1, 20) * 0.000001` and @HansPassant, thanks for your suggestion to change the variable to double, it perfectly worked.